# How to set an entered in string as a variable? C++

Tags: c++

Code (this isn't the whole code, just the part I want to figure out):

```
int x = 12; int y = 14; int z = 6;
char move_from; char move_to;

cout << " Boxes:   x   y   z" << endl;
cout << "Values:" << "   " << x << "  " << y << "  " << z << endl << endl;

cout << "Enter the values you want to move around: ";
cin >> move_from >> move_to;

move_from = move_from - move_from;   //Calculations to move the values around
move_to = move_to + move_from;

cout << " Boxes:   x   y   z" << endl;
cout << "Values:" << "   " << x << "  " << y << "  " << z << endl << endl;  // Updated values are shown
```

What I am trying to do is when the user enters in the values the user wants to move. The program does it accordingly with what the user enters in. So for example if the user enters in xy, the value in x gets added to y and the value in x is going to be set to 0.

Sample Output ( What I want it to do):

```
 Boxes:   x   y   z
Values:   12  14  6

Enter the values you want to move around: xy
 Boxes:   x   y   z
Values:   0   26  6
```

Sample Output( What it does...):

```
 Boxes:   x   y   z
Values:   12  14  6

Enter the values you want to move around: xy
 Boxes:   x   y   z
Values:   12  14  6
```

The problem I am having is that the user input is saved as a string so the calculations doesn't really work as I want to, but instead I had to write about 6 different if statements to move the values around.

I would like to know if it's possible to just take the user input and for it to just do the calculations as I did above, and to reduce the clutter of if statements I have in my actual code.

Thank You!

Comment: Your description is not clear enough for me to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Variables are a compile-time concept and have no special meaning during the execution of the program. You'd have to write some logic to handle different inputs.

Comment: Doesn't `move_from - move_from` set the value to 0?

Comment: I updated my question with sample outputs of what I want the code to do and what it actually does. Thats basically what I get when I run my code.

Comment: You can't.  What you can do is store your variables and values in a map and then access by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a lambda to convert a user-inputted `char` to a reference to corresponding variable, something like

```
auto char_to_var = [&](char var) -> int&
                   {
                       switch (var)
                       {
                       case 'x': return x;
                       case 'y': return y;
                       default:  return z;
                       }
                   };
```

and use the converted reference to perform your "move", something like

```
auto &move_from_var = char_to_var(move_from);
auto &move_to_var = char_to_var(move_to);
move_to_var += move_from_var;
move_from_var = 0;
```